How to Style and Display JSON Response from API on the Same Page After File Upload
I’m working on a simple interface to test an API that returns a JSON file after file upload. I have used basic HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, but I’m encountering several issues, particularly with CORS. I've tried various solutions for CORS, but none of them worked.
Here’s what I’ve done so far, which works perfectly but only shows the raw JSON:
  <form method="post" action="http://my-api-url" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
      <label for="files">Choose file to upload</label>
      <br>
      <br><input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple /><br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
      <button id="sendButton">Envoyer</button>
    </div>
  </form>

The issue:
After submitting the form, the JSON is displayed on a new page, but it’s unstyled and difficult to read. I want to display the JSON response on the same page, and ideally, I'd like to style it to make it more readable.
I’ve tried:

using JavaScript fetch() to send the file and handle the response, but I ran into CORS issues. I tried solutions like setting headers, using a proxy, or changing the mode to no-cors, but none of these resolved the problem.

Using a simple form POST (as shown above) bypasses CORS, but I end up with a raw JSON response in a new page, which is not ideal for my use case.


Is there a way to display the JSON response on the same page without opening a new one, while still bypassing the CORS issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
PS: I’m relatively new and may have made some mistakes along the way, so I apologize if I missed anything obvious!

Try this old trick: Add <iframe name="response">  and on the <form target="response">. See this post.

Is that your API you're sending to, or some 3rd party you don't have any control over? If it's your API, just set the necessary response headers to allow CORS.

This is an API over which I have no control. I found a solution by using the CORS extension for Google Chrome. By adjusting the settings of the extension, I was able to resolve the CORS issue. This solution doesn’t directly answer my question, it allowed me to work around the problem and move forward ^^ Thank you so much for your answers!
